# Writing code for main function in order to find sum of digits in a number

Tags: python, geany

I need to write a short program that asks for positive integer, reads the number and then prints results of operations by both functions.

I've already written both fuctions which look like this:

```
def sumdigits(n):
    
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0):
       
        sum = sum + (n % 10)
        n = n//10
       
    return sum
   
n = int(input("enternumber: "))
print(sumdigits(n))
```

```
def sumdigits(no):
    return 0 if no == 0 else int(no % 10) + sumdigits(int(no / 10)) 
   

n = int(input("enternumber: "))
print(sumdigits(n))
```

The thing that I struggle with is merging these two together in order to make 1 general complex function that will show results of both functions.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use inner functions. For example:

```py
def sumdigits(n):
    def loop(n):
        sum = 0
        while (n != 0):
            sum = sum + (n % 10)
            n = n//10
        return sum
    def recurse(n):
        return 0 if n == 0 else int(n % 10) + recurse(int(n / 10)) 
    return loop(n), recurse(n)

n = int(input("enternumber: "))
print(sumdigits(n))
```